# Eloquent ORM and relative where time statement

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I'm using ORM Eloquent and I need to filter all models using a date interval and an own property of the model.

The raw SQL would be:

```
SELECT * FROM model WHERE start >= NOW() - INTERVAL duration MINUTES
```

Where `start` is a `datetime` and `duration` is an int of model table.

Is it possible to write a where statement? Is there an alternative to write a RAW query?

```
 Event::where('start', '>=', ? )->get();
```

The `start` field is indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to go about this is to calculate the interval on the application side.

E.g.: checking for a 30 minutes interval:

```
$minutesPast = (new DateTime('-30 minutes'))->format('d/m/Y h:i:s');
Event::where('start', '>=', $minutesPast )->get();
```

I rather calculate times and dates on the application side anyway, since that way there's a single source of truth, and I don't have to worry about the DB server maybe not being on the same timezone as the application server, etc.